# easy question involving definition of bousfield localization

Tags: algebraic-topology

Easy question: If $X$ is a space/spectrum such that $H_*(X)=0$ (where $H_*$ is ordinary homology), then why does this imply the Bousfield localization $L_HX$ is contractible?

My attempt: $L_HX$ is $H$-local, so since $H_*(X)=0$ we have $[X, L_HX]=0$, and in particular the localization $\eta:X \to L_HX$ is nullhomotopic. Why does this imply $L_HX$ is contractible?

The reason I think this is the case is this is used on p. 71 on Ravenel's Orange Book (Nilpotence and Periodicity in stable homotopy theory)

Comment: By the same kind of method, you want to show $[L_H X, L_H X]$ is trivial, and you haven't yet used the other defining property of the map $X \to L_H X$.

Comment: Aha, thanks Prof. Lawson. The other property you mention is that $\eta$ is an H-equivalence, so $0=H(X) \simeq H(L_HX)$, so then $[L_HX, L_HX]=0$ and hence the identity map is null-homotopic.